# what i am missing in my php code to generate link?

Tags: php

I am trying to generate 300 link in serial with php 
very confused plz help what im missing.

```
$i         = 0;
$c         = 300;
do {
    $i++;
    echo "<a href=http://deewayz.in/user/" . $i . "/><img src="http://deewayz.in/images/user/" . $i . "/profile_q.jpg" border=0></a>";
} while ($c > $i);
```

**out put i want is:**

```
<a href=http://deewayz.in/user/1/>
<img src="http://deewayz.in/images/user/1/profile_q.jpg" border=0></a>
<a href=http://deewayz.in/user/2/>
<img src="http://deewayz.in/images/user/2/profile_q.jpg" border=0></a>

so on....
```

Error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'http' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: i type wrong but it was not issue :) ($c > $i);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 echo "<a href='http://deewayz.in/user/ $i/'><img src='http://deewayz.in/images/user/$i/profile_q.jpg' border=0></a>";
```

php parses variables automatically within double quotes

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape quotes that are inside quotes:

```
echo "<a href=http://deewayz.in/user/" . $i . "/><img src=\"http://deewayz.in/images/user/" . $i . "/profile_q.jpg\" border=0></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would chaange what you have as your loop to this

```
        do {
$i++;
echo "<a href='http://deewayz.in/user/" . $i . "'/><img src='http://deewayz.in/images/user/" . $i . "/profile_q.jpg' border=0></a>";
 } while ($c > $v);
```